# Does the independence assumption interact with the generalizability of results in hierarchical designs?

Tags: chi-squared-test, multilevel-analysis, independence, assumptions

A friend recently posed to me the following problem:

Is it possible to do a Chi-square on test results for a group of participants to determine if they made more of type A errors or type B errors?

I know there are specific statistics intended for within-subjects table designs.  However, I wanted to see if I could think through an answer in the context of Chi-square.  My friend mentioned that their big concern was that doing so in the context of Chi-square would represent a violation of the assumption of independence

After thinking about it for a while, I came to the realization that I wasn't 100% certain about the nature of the assumption of independence in hierarchical designs.  My impression is that there is a way in which the assumption of independence depends on the hierarchy of the design one wishes to generalize to.  For example, in the above problem would I be justified in using Chi-square if I only wanted to generalize to the Type A/B error rate of those particular subjects?